# Turning a line into italic doesn't always work - why?

Tags: support, markdown

I noticed while trying to consistently format e.g. error messages in posts that the "italicizing" in the markdown editor doesn't seem to work reliably...

Can someone explain why it does work on lines 1 and 4, but **not** on lines 2 and 3, in this case here??

> *Error messages: The merge process could not set the status of the
>   subscription correctly.*
>   *(Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147200963)*
>   *Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_MScheckIsPubOfSub'.*
>   *(Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2812)*

Is there anything I can do to make it work even on those pesky lines, too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The underscores mess it up:

> *Error messages: The merge process could not set the status of the
>   subscription correctly.*
>   *(Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147200963)*
>   *Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_MScheckIsPubOfSub'.*
>   *(Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2812)*

```
> *Error messages: The merge process could not set the status of the
subscription correctly.*  
> *(Source: MSSQL\_REPL, Error number: MSSQL\_REPL-2147200963)*  
> *Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp\_MScheckIsPubOfSub'.*   
> *(Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2812)*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed after the next build; see point 1. in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229236/115866).