# How can I use italic text with "computername\IIS_IUSRS"?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I italicize text that contain underscores?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147117/how-can-i-italicize-text-that-contain-underscores)
>   [Turning a line into italic doesn’t always work - why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155263/turning-a-line-into-italic-doesnt-always-work-why)

How can I style the text below to look italic?

computername\IIS_IUSRS

It's not *computername\IIS_IUSRS* - so much I get. What the duck?! (typo intentional)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the underscore with backslashes:

*computername\IIS_IUSRS*

```
*computername\IIS\_IUSRS*
```

The duck will send you the bill.

Comment: Ah, I tested escaping both the backslash and the underscore but not simultaneously... My quacks to all the ducks! Thanks. Escaping the first, I can understand - it's **the** escape character. But why on Earth the need to escape the latter?! It's not LaTeX... I also took the liberty to edit your reply so that the next poor soul needs not to click edit to see the source code of your answer.

Comment: Markdown has semantics for _.

Comment: What's *markdown*? The opposite of *markup*?! As in the process of **not** denoting stuff in the structure?

Comment: Markdown is the name of the text formatting language in use here, from whence cometh the * and the ** and all that.